# ionic 3: black screen with Android App on device

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Yesterday, I built and run my app on my Android device and this version worked fine.

Since, I improved my app (content view and controller of some modules) and today, I have a black screen on device.

### Tests where app is OK

- When I execute `ionic serve`
- When I build another Ionic app (not this one) and run on device

### Tests where app fails on device

- When I execute `ionic cordova run android --debug`
- When I use the same version like yesterday
- When I try to rebuild a already tagged version (So qualified and tested)

I think that maybe my build configuration is corrupted but I don't know how.

I tried to:

- remove and re-add Android platform
- re-install all NPM modules

but nothing these steps does not fix the issue.

On device, I can't access to "Inspect device" tool of Chrome to see if I have JS problem.

Do you have any idea to resolve my problem please?

## EDIT

After more tests, I found the following behavior:

> If I change the ID of `<widget id="new-app-id">` in `config.xml`, app runs fine on device!

Any idea on this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: If you wait on the black screen do you eventually get AppName isn't responding? (I am asking since I ran into this same issue today, no solution yet)

Comment: Check console log there might be errors.

Comment: one small comment - the screen is actually dark grey ;) this may help searching others and I am pretty sure as I faced exactly same issue with fb sdk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After many tests and research, I found the root cause and can solve the issue.

### Solution

Remove the plugin `cordova-plugin-facebook4` and re-add it with SDK VERSION to `4.35.0`
For older `cordova-android` version, the version shall be defined as described [here](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/android/README.md#older-cordova-cli)

So, run:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="<APP-ID>" --variable APP_NAME="<APP-NAME>" --variable ANDROID_SDK_VERSION="4.35.0"
```

### Root cause

As decribed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111298/how-to-solve-app-launch-app-is-stuck-on-white-screen), Facebook SDK version 4.36.0 is not stable and causes the stuck in main thread.

This behavior is visible on my App (with "monitor tools" of Android SDK)

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much! I had same problem for a while and  your answer helps me!!

Comment: Great quick fix. Saved me hours. I would have taken decision to rebuild app for not finding out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **some application with your previous app-id(package name) is already installed on your device**. Uninstall that application and try with your previous app-id and it should work.