# ionic No Network Security Config specified

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

my app is stoped in splash with message error in console:

```
 09-02 23:26:29.099 3684-3684/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-02 23:26:29.117 3684-3684/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-02 23:26:29.253 3684-3684/com.x.X k E/com.facebook.internal.AttributionIdentifiers: getAttributionIdentifiers should not be called from the main thread
09-02 23:26:29.275 3684-3700/com.x.X  k D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Comment: Same here and should be related to this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111298/how-to-solve-app-launch-app-is-stuck-on-white-screen?noredirect=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic 3: black screen with Android App on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119168/ionic-3-black-screen-with-android-app-on-device)

Comment: Flagged this question since it looks to me a possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119168/ionic-3-black-screen-with-android-app-on-device/52137216 . OP might try the solution provided and check if it answers the question.