# FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error

Tags: android

My app, which was running normally, has not been running with the log below since a few days ago.

**FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE**

Answers to other questions such as check Internet connectivity or google play service were not helpful.
If it fails to get token from Firebase, is the app not running?

For your information, we have changed the account registered with google play console.

Comment: check app in firebase console. may be some api keys or permissions expired. i am facing same issue with my app that using facebook sdk. my app failed to get user_photos permission in token and when i checked facebook developer console. The problem was there in developer console

Comment: compare the google-services.json file in the server and in the app. If they do not contain a matching item, update the file in the app

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan Checking the Facebook console, user_friends permission is not authorized.
However, my app is not using user_friends permissions.

Comment: may be your app using some permissions related to user_friends and check Firebase Console too.i think Firebase not sending token to your app

Comment: @MuhammadHassaan Couldn't find about any Facebook or permission on the Firebase console. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me where to look into.

Comment: dont check Facebook permissions there in firebase console. only check that your application and api keys are properly integrated in firebase or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, problem was with the FacebookSDK that the latest version is broken.

this worked for me: 
[How to solve app launch - app is stuck on white screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111298/how-to-solve-app-launch-app-is-stuck-on-white-screen)